# Changing mysql default port

Tags: iptables

I got the following 2 commands from mysql website. I tried to change the default mysql port from 3306 to 4040 and back. But it did not work as expected.

Redirect to Proxy:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s ! 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4040
```

Back to default:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -s ! 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4040
```

What am I missing here?

Update:

The change is being shown up in the status as follows:

```
# /etc/init.d/iptables status
Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REDIRECT   tcp  -- !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 redir ports 4040 
2    REDIRECT   tcp  -- !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 redir ports 4040 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just configure MySQL to listen on port 4040? A firewall redirect seems a bit overkill. The [MySQL webpage](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html) you refer to is about configuring a MySQL proxy, not about changing the default port.

Comment: Because I do not want to restart mysql service. It is OK to restart iptables. The same page has a section called "simple logging" from where I have picked these 2 commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, you have the ports the wrong way around. You want to redirect from 4040 to 3306. So try:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s ! 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 4040 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3306
```

You also need to make sure you remove the other incorrect rules as well.

P.S. If this is a production system that can't even afford downtime to change the listener port, you should not be trying `iptables` rules from the Internet! Test it on a test machine first.

Comment: How do I remove the rules set earlier?

Comment: @shantanuo: Use the `-D` command that you listed in your question.

Comment: >> Test it on a test machine first. # yes. ofcourse

Comment: @shantanuo: Sorry, I don't want to be responsible if someone running a nuclear power plant takes my advice and causes a meltdown :)